# Can Company Profits Be Split Equally Amongst Two Partners With Different Shares?

Tags: canada, shareholders, incorporation, equity

I intend to create an 'inc.' moral entity in Quebec, Canada (corporation).

Can I own 75% of the shares while splitting profit 50/50 with my partner? (In a legally binding manner)

Comment: Is a "moral entity" a feature of  law in Canada or Quebec?

Comment: Why do you want to split ownership of the company in a different split than your profits (and potentially losses)? Generally profits are a function of ownership; what other benefits do you expect to derive from your 75% ownership stake?

Comment: @GeorgeWhite A corporation. Sorry, I translated it roughly from French, which I understand now is not as straight forward as I thought.

Comment: @sharur Because this is the best compromise we have reached. The idea is to have some sort of legally binding agreement which states that for 3 years all profit (and losses) are shared equally among us despite us owning different share proportions. After this period of time, the profit and losses can be split according to shares. Is this something possible?

Comment: @ursulet would recommend editing your question to include this information, as that changes the situation (the temporality of the profit sharing) and doing so may yield a better answer being put forward, and comments on this site are ephemeral, so they can disappear over time; Also, welcome to the stackExchange network. We're a little different from other websites, so I would recommend you take the [tour](https://law.stackexchange.com/tour/).

Comment: Ownership also can affect voting for board members and other critical issues and the division of proceeds if the company is sold.  You can look into using different classes of stock with different voting and dividend rights.

Comment: Thank you for the very helpful and directed answers! Also thanks for the noob tips.

Comment: It is worth recognizing that there is distinction between what is possible and what is desirable. Usually, there is a motive for wanting a 75% ownership split, but a 50% profit split. Is the issue liquidation preferences? Is it relative work? Is it a tax concern? Not all ways of doing so may achieve your goals. Also, assuming in advance that you want a corporation, rather than some other form of entity, may be unreasonably ruling out better solutions. If I had clients in the U.S. who wanted to achieve that goal, I would not organize the business as a corporation, I would us an LLC or LLP.

Answer (score 3):

[australia](/questions/tagged/australia)

Companies can have different classes of shares with different rights: rights to dividends, voting, distribution of assets on winding up etc. Basically, it’s pretty much completely customisable.

Comment: Good answer, thanks.